# ReactJS autocomplete from React Bootstrap not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to build an autocomplete search field, using [this form component](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-control-props) from React Bootstrap, which is rendered as a input by the browser.

Here's what I did in my React component:

```html
<FormControl
 id="frenchToEnglishInput"
 placeholder="type a word..."
 aria-label="Recipient's username"
 autocomplete="on"
 data={frenchToEnglishWords}
 onChange={this.fetchFrenchToEnglish}
 renderItem = {item => {
   return (
     <div>
       {item}
     </div>
   );
 }}
/>
```

the `frenchToEnglishWords` array is declared outside the component as a `var`, as I intend to update it as I type some value into the input field.

Now here is the function that triggers the `onChange` event :

```js
fetchFrenchToEnglish = async () => {
    if(document.getElementById("frenchToEnglishInput").value!==''){

      axios.get(dictionaryURIs.english.French_English+""+document.getElementById("frenchToEnglishInput").value)
      .then(response => {
          frenchToEnglishWords = response.data
      })

    }
  }
```

The request is made from MongoDb, after setting up an autocomplete index on a collection, but this part works fine.

My question is, why is the only "autocomplete" I'm getting is the one made of the previous words I've typed ?

[image: input wrong autocomplete]

Or maybe the array I'm using as input data must be a `const` (as I've seen in many examples) and not a `var` ?
When I do type in some word, I do not get any autosuggestion from the `frenchToEnglishWords`, which is being updated from the DB.

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

**You need to use State!**

This is not working because the data field is not a State, you need to **bind** the `fetchFrenchToEnglish` function to the data state.

But first of all, there's no reason to use `var`, because the most differences between them is just scope and immutability, [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-let-and-const-keywords-in-javascript/) is more about it.

Also, you can use hooks like `useState` and `useRef` to no use `getElementById`.